# Upgrading an old mac mini intel 1.1 for Lion

Tags: macos, mac, upgrade

I'm looking to buy an older mac mini (v1.1) CoreDuo 1.66Ghz 2Gb DDR2, 80Gb HD.

My research shows the original OS was Mac OS X 10.4.11.

So my question is: if i will upgrade my CPU from T2300 to T7200 (2.0Ghz,Core2Duo) and the [FirmWare from 1.1 to 2.1](http://forum.netkas.org/index.php/topic,874.msg15441.html#msg15441) so I can increase the ram from 2 to 4 Gb.

Will this configuration work for lion (Yes, i know 1.1 is not compatible with installer)?

I mean installed lion 10.7.5 will work good like now works Tiger and other soft like ilife 09, ableton 8, reason 5, audacity? or it will lagging?

also i need lion for my wifi adapter TP-LINK TL-WN7722N (i think i can startup this adapter with atheros fix or other kexts)

Comment: I've tried to edit a bit for grammar since you indicated English wasn't your strength. Consider thinning this to have one question per question in case someone can answer part but not all of your concerns. How do you intend to modify the firmware on the Mac?

Comment: i found this tutorial http://forum.netkas.org/index.php/topic,874.msg15441.html#msg15441 but now i can't do this because ijust make order from ebay for CPU T7200. 64bit need i think and just waiting.

Comment: hardware update i will do because this mac looks very slow for me

Comment: It can be done. But you need an SSD to speedup your machine, the original 80gb hd is slow. Further, replace the PRAM battery with a fresh one (CR2032 lithium 3V) when you are at it.

Comment: ok but for what i need replace CR2032 battery?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, it will not work.

Long answer: Lion requires a 64bit processor and the Yonah processor on the mini1,1 still is partially 32 bit. You will NOT be able to boot in to Lion because you cannot boot a 64 bit kernel. However, it is possible to use a separate disk to boot into a custom boot loader and then load Lion from there (much like trying to get a MacPro1,1 to boot Lion). This is a definite hack, and not something I would recommend to anyone, especially for a super-low-end machine like this mini. It will not be happy.

Also, this machine has a SATA-I interface, so even with an SSD in it, it will still be slow.

Comment: all this i know. I'm asking about work. if i will add Core2Duo T7200 +2 more GB Ram, will lion work fine on this old machine? Fine-i means without freezing, lagging and other negative stuff or problems are in sata-1 and 80HD?

Comment: If you get around the inability to boot by using a boot loader, then yes, Lion will run. It will run slowly, but it will run. If you expect it to run without lagging? Well, that seems unlikely. I ran 107 on an unsupported MacPro and it ran perfectly well, but that is a much more powerful machine. The only person who can decide if it's running "well" is you, but it will run.

Comment: thanx for reply. i will check later. my CPU 2.0Ghz still not come yet. Now i have installed Mac OS X 10.6 for ready for upgrading but it so slow for this configuration and i dont think that CPU Core2Duo make miracle in this stuff. So i thinking about SSD  later.